# neo4j cypher SET to each edge attribute from numpy array

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

If I have a cypher query (using `py2neo`):

```
edges = graph.run("MATCH (r:edge) RETURN r.col1 r.col2 r.col3").to_data_frame()
```

and this returns a dataframe of columns.

Then I do some operations in python and pass the dataframe through a ML algorithm to make some predictions, so ultimately I end up with a prediction for every edge in `edges` - let's call that `y_predict` (which has the same length as `edges`).

Now I want to take this new array/list `y_predict` and set a new attribute on each of the edges that were just returned. But I just want the first value in `y_predict` to be assigned to this attribute on the first edge in `edges`, and the second to the second, and so on...

If I run:

```
edges = graph.run(f"MATCH (r:edge) \
SET r.att1 = {y_predict}")
```

this will set the entire list to every edge in `edges` instead of each value individually.

Is there a way to do this in cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need some way of uniquely identifying each `edge` so that you can match the computed `y_predict` to the correct node. Below I assume that the triplet `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` are unique.

I'm not familiar with py2neo but in straight Cypher you can pass an array as a JSON string and then walk thru the array using the `unwind` command.

Assuming you pass JSON shaped like this

```
{predictions: [{col1: "A", col2: "B", col3: "C", prediction: 75}, {col1: "D", col2: "E", col3: "F", prediction: 100}]}
```

then this Cypher command will set `y_predict` on each node

```
unwind {predictions} as p
match (e:edge {col1: p.col1, col2: p.col2, col3: p.col3})
set e.y_predict = p.prediction
```

To use the node's ID instead of the three col values, the JSON could be formatted like this

```
{predictions: [{e_id: 72, prediction: 75}, {e_id: 67, prediction: 100}]}
```

and used with this Cypher

```
unwind {predictions} as p
match (e:edge) where id(e) = p.e_id
set e.y_predict = p.prediction
```

Comment: Can I match on id? Like: `match (e:edge {id(e): id})` ?

Comment: I expanded the answer to include an example using the nodes' IDs

Comment: Does this run line by line? I'm noticing that this takes quite a long time to run. Is there any way to just merge them in a vectorized manner?

Comment: Yes, it's row by row. How many nodes are you updating? The slowness may be due to a large transaction.

Unfortunately unwind doesn't support periodic commit. If it's the large transaction causing the slowness then you can either break your updates into smaller batches or use something like Neo4j's LOAD CSV command.